# AutoComplete using two QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

I know how to use `QCompleter` class.
code:

```
QStringList wordList;
wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta";

QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

But I want to join `QString` like `xxxxx.yyyyy` when I type `xx` all the auto completion from that `QStringlist` should appear drop down, so after I select the appropriate ones, if I enter `.` auto completion form 2nd `QStringList` should drop down.

I know I have not put across my point properly, but it is really tough to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

A basic idea which came to my mind is that you should register a key press listener on that `QLineEdit` which only listens for `.` character. Once user has entered a `.` character you should prepend all characters have been entered so far to the second `QStringList` and feet it to the `QCompleter`.

Steps:

- Apply the first `QStringList`.
- When user typed `.`, prepend what has been entered so far to the second `QStringList` and apply it to the `QCompleter`.